# Why am I not getting a response from express server?

Tags: express, redis

Sending a logout request to my server but I'm never getting a reply. The logout function is being called and the userID key is being deleted from my redis cache but I never get a response. Here's my code.

```
export const logout = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("logout called");
  const { userID } = req.user;

  client.del(userID.toString, (err, reply) => {
    console.log("inside client.del");
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500);
    } else {
      return res.status(200);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of callback, you should use promise

```
export const logout = async (req, res) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        console.log("logout called");
            const { userID } = req.user;
        
            client.del(userID.toString, (err, reply) => {
            console.log("inside client.del");
            if (err) {
                reject(res.status(500));
            } else {
                resolve(res.status(200));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The presumed point of this `logout()` function is to actually do the logout in the database and then send a response to the http request represented by the `req` and `res` arguments.  Your suggestion does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

`res.status()` does not send a response from the server.  All it does is set the status as a property on the response object that will go with some future call that actually sends the response.

It is meant to be used in something like this:

```
res.status(500).send("Database error");
```

If you look at the [Express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status) for `res.status()`, you will see these examples:

```
res.status(403).end()
res.status(400).send('Bad Request')
res.status(404).sendFile('/absolute/path/to/404.png')
```

And, see that they all are followed by some other method that actually causes the response to be sent.

---

And, if you still had any doubt, you can look in the [Express code repository](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/43cc56eb9e529774535a992422ee90b5c9e15ff9/lib/response.js#L66) and see this:

```
res.status = function status(code) {
  this.statusCode = code;
  return this;
};
```

Which shows that it's just setting a property on the response object and not actually sending the response yet.

---

You can use `res.sendStatus()` instead which will BOTH set the status and send the response:

```
export const logout = (req, res) => {
  console.log("logout called");
  const { userID } = req.user;

  client.del(userID.toString, (err, reply) => {
    console.log("inside client.del");
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
};
```

Note, I removed the two `return` keywords since they don't accomplish anything useful in this particular context.

I also removed the `async` keyword from the function definition since it was not doing anything useful in this context.